# Python 2s complement to 1s complement

Tags: python-3.x, binary

Can anyone help me please?
I can't seem to find how to change binary 2s complement to 1s complement in python :/ (e.g. 1011010111010111)
if anyone has the answer or any hints for me, that would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I'm a beginner and I don't know a lot about python yet, go easy on me ty.

Comment: A good first stop is usually the [definition of the term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones'_complement) and from there try implementing some Python code to explore. It's often educational to do this on paper first, or even in a spreadsheet, to get a feel for the transformations required and come up with some test cases.

Comment: Okay thank you for the quick answer! I'll try and get some research into it.